# Best way to extract value from pandas dataframe for mathematical operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scalar

Say I want to find a value (`value_wanted`) located under a specific column (`col`) of a dataframe (`df`) and is found based on some criteria (`df['A']==cond1`) and use that value to multiply/add/subtract/etc something.

Right now I'm obtaining the value like this:

```
value_wanted = df.iloc[:,col][(df['A']==cond1)].reset_index(drop=True).iat[0]
important_stff = value_wanted * 1000
```

So value I want is located in the `col` column of `df`, but the row is determined by the `df['A'] == cond1`

If it helps, I would do this in Excel `=index(df!A:Z, match(cond1, df!A:A,0)),col)`

Is there a better/cleaner of way obtaining just the value from a dataframe?

Comment: What if your condition returns multiple rows that satisfy it?

Comment: That's a good question. I won't come across in my specific application (at least, not yet), but I might. I guess I'd to iterate over the values it found if there were more than one.

Answer (score 1):

*** answer edited after comments ***
First off having column names be numbers is not optimum.  side note: You ever wonder why variables in Python can't start with numbers?
Keeping track of what is data and what is metadata is difficult.  Give it some good names to help you and others who read this keep it straight.

```
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5), columns=[x for x in range(5)])
important_stuff = a[a[0]==cond1][3].iloc[0] * 1000
```

`a[0] == cond1` where 0 is the "column name"

the `[3]` will give you the column '3' data

`iloc[0]` will give you the first element

Comment: Thanks for input! Ah I guess I can't just use `df.col` if my column labels are integers. I think that's why I used `iloc`

Comment: Actually, doesn't this only work if the `value_wanted` is at row index 0?

Comment: I did need to change that.  Thank you.